# jQuery datepicker doesn´t work when publish

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I do have this jQuery datepicker in a mvc app

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dayNamesMin: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mie", "Jue", "Vie", "Sab"],
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showAnim: "fold"
        });
```

and I show it in this @Html.EditorFor

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fechaEvento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fechaEvento, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control left-border-none", @readonly = "readonly", @id = "datepicker", @title = "especifique fecha en que impartirá el evento", @Value = ViewBag.fechaEvento } })
                        </div>
                        <p class="help-block">click para especificar fecha</p>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fechaEvento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
```

and works just fine when running from Visual Studio

[image]

but when I publish the App and access via web the Datepicker is transparent and it is hard to see the date and pick one.

[image]

these are the css and scripts

```
    <link href="@Url.Content("/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="@Url.Content("/Content/themes/base/all.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="@Url.Content("/Content/themes/base/base.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="@Url.Content("/Content/themes/base/theme.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="@Url.Content("/Content/themes/base/dialog.css")" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js")"></script>
```

could you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Check the browser's network requests for missing resources or script errors. Sometimes when you publish the resource paths becomes broken.

Comment: better render the script and stylesheets via bundling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the CDN version, it clearly can't find the .css file when you build the app for some reason, is the path right ? Upper/Lowercase correct ? Images of jQuery UI in the correct directory that can be accessed by the code ?

***CDN VERSION***

```
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js")"></script>
```

And try to do the same with the css check [the complete CDN list here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui/1.12.1)

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css